# Best way to allow local users login while using OpenID Connect?

Tags: authentication-authorization

I'm trying to find the best way to allow local users login on a D9 installation that is setup to log the majority of users via OpenID Connect on a keycloak server which I don't handle myself.

I may have found a bug in core/module [showcore parameter does not show core login form anymore](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_connect/issues/3284395) but more importantly I'm not sure what the best way to achieve my goal is.

Assuming the bug is indeed a bug and it gets patched, is it the way to go or am I missing something, like an additional module or a way to configure OpenID Connect to allow local users?
As things are now all users are immediately redirected for login to the keycloak server so local login isn't possible at all until ?showcore comes back at the very least.

Comment: If the openID module is overriding the core login route, the simplest method is probably to extra routes via a custom module that clone the core ones that you need. A custom login route may be sufficient.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong I'd avoid investing the time needed to learn to write a custom module, if at all possible, but I do appreciate your insight.